# what does the "-g" flag do in the command "npm install -g <something>"?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm following examples that use the `-g` flag when using `npm install` but I can't figure out through the help system what the `-g` flag is doing.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`-g` tells `npm` to install the named module so that it's accessible globally.

But it's important to understand that `-g` is typically only used for packages that provide command-line utilities so that their executable components are available in the system `PATH`.

If you have multiple programs that `require` the same package, each program should install the package locally. If you really want to share an installed package by installing it globally, you have to also use `npm link`.

See the docs on the topic of globally installed packages [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally).

Answer (score 15):

If you do `npm help install` you will see that:

> ```
>   o   npm install (in package directory, no arguments):
>
>       Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.
>
>       In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended  to  the  com-
>       mand), it installs the current package context (ie, the current
>       working directory) as a global package.
> ```

Comment: Not that helpful to just copy-paste the help text, especially if you don't know what a global package is or how it differs from a local package.

Answer (score 3):

Take the [express module](http://expressjs.com/) as an example.  If it was previously installed with the -g option, you could write `express` anywhere, to create a skeleton application.